# Error Using Interfaces: class Main inherits unrelated defaults for display() from types first and second public class Main implements first, second

Tags: java, interface

Not getting why Im getting a Compilation error for this code. Like which property of Interface Im missing out while predicting the output.

```
public class Main implements first, second
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main object = new Main();
        object.display();
    }
}

interface first {
       default public void display() {
              System.out.println("This is the display function of interface first");
    }
}

interface second {
      default public void display() {
             System.out.println("This is the display function of interface second");
    }
}
```

Comment: When `new Main().display()` is called, what would you expect the output to be? Why? That should answer your question.

Comment: Does any of our answers resolved your problem? If so please accept it to indicate the question resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is a very straight forward and explicit language, that doesn't leave much space for uncertainty. That's why basically everything ambiguous will give you a compilation error.

You have to tell Java which `display` method you actually want to use:

```
public class Main implements first, second {
    @Override
    public void display() {
        first.super.display();
        // or: second.super.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the `display()` method implementation in the `Main` class.
Something like this:

```java
public class Main implements first, second
{
    @Override
    public void display() {
         System.out.println("This is the display function of main");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main object = new Main();
        object.display();
    }
}
```

Or if you want to use one of the methods defined in `first` or `second` interfaces as is you can do define it

```java
public class Main implements first, second
{
    @Override
    first.super.display();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main object = new Main();
        object.display();
    }
}
```

As mentioned by Benjamin

Answer (score 1):

Unless you override it inside Main class Java cannot know what method to call in this case :)